# calculating integer to array location java

Tags: java, if-statement, multidimensional-array, modulo

Don't understand how to solve this.
I need to accept a seat number as a parameter (seat). And then convert that seat number into a row and column index for the two-dimensional array.

to check myself I've been assuming there are 10 rows (0-9) and 2 seatsPerRow (0-1) and picking a seat from 1-20 out of that to check the math. BUT There can be any amount of rows and columns. This is just what I'm using to check myself.

```
static void isAvailable(int seat, boolean seat[][]) {

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;

    if (seat > 0 && seat <= (getRows() * getSeatsPerRow())){
        row = (seat ) % getRows();
        column = (seat - 1) % getSeatsPerRow;
        seat[row][column] = false;
    }
}
```

Assuming the seats were arranged this way:

```
            seatsPerRow
       0   1   2   3   4   5   6 

    0 (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) (7)

 r  1 (8) (9) (10)(11)(12)(13)(14)

 o  2 (15)(16)(17)(18)(19)(20)(21)

 w  3  ...

 s  4  ...

    .

    .

    .
```

Say I wanted to find seat 11. It would be seat[1][3]. I don't understand how to convert the seat number to the location on the 2-d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming seats are numbered starting at 1, you can get the column index simply by using:

```
int column = (seatNum - 1) % seat[0].length;
```

You can then find the row with a simple expression:

```
int row = (int) ((seatNum - 1) / seat[0].length);
```

Then, you'd get the actual element by doing:

```
seats[row][column]
```

Both these expressions should work for *all dimensions* of the `seat` array (except 0 x 0).

The first line will use modulo to find the *remainder* of `seatNum / seat[0].length`, or basically the seat number divided by the number of seats per row. This will restruct `column` to the correct range.

Next, the second line will divide the number of seats by the length of a row, which will find the row itself. We then cast it to an int with `(int)`, which truncates it, dropping any decimal that may have resulted from the operation. In this case, we're actually performing purely integer math, so the cast is unnecessary.

Comment: What does seat[0] mean? It's a two-dimensional array. I only understand the basics of java.

Comment: @user1368970 It will get the first *row* of the array. We can then use `.length` on that to get the length of a row, not of the outer array, which is the number of rows, aka the length of a column.

Comment: I'm still not understanding right, when I do the math it doesn't come out with the correct row or column numbers. Check my update please.

Comment: Ok! Totally understand now! Thanks so much!

Comment: Is it really necessary to cast to int?

Comment: @Makoto No, it's not, as I actually mentioned. I often find it a useful guide, though, since it helps to demonstrate that we're truncating the value. Still, that's obviously a stylistic option up to the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the seating arrangement is like so:

```
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6
 7  8
 9 10
11 12
13 14
15 16
17 18
19 20



int col = (seat % 2 == 0)? 1:0;
int row = (int)Math.ceil(seat / 2.0f);
```

Comment: Math.ceil() mrthod gives the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to the argument. for more refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29

Answer (score 1):

The modulus operator will be invaluable here, since it can determine which seat we'll want to wind up using.

First, let's take in our assumptions and convert them to something more abstract:

- There are N seats, where N = 20.  We take N to be our rows.
- There are K rows, where K = 2.  We take K to be our columns.
- Given this, there are N/K seats per row.

Now, we can use some modulus mathematics to work the rest of the problem out.  Let's declare our array of seats now.

```
boolean[][] seats = new boolean[N][K]; //presumed
```

If we want to claim seat 13, then we need to figure two things out:

- What **row** is the seat in?
- What **column** is the seat in?

Given the above, the math for the row is as follows:

```
int row = (seatWanted % N)-1; // (13 % 10)-1 = 2.
```

Now, the column is similarly easy to find - we would use integer division instead of modulus, though.

```
int column = seatWanted / K; // 13 / 10 = 1.
```

The rest is an exercise to the reader, but we would want to mark `seats[2][1]` as taken.

Comment: So, in writing this class, n and k would be the parameters of rows and seatsPerRow(which is column)?

Comment: Ultimately I presume that you can pull the length of each row and column off an array by using `.length`.  N and K are there for illustrative purposes.